# Dropzone.js and overwrite message

Tags: dropzone.js

I have fully working code to upload files using Dropzone.js library. Then I have tried to get a message to display Yes or No buttons to overwrite existing file.

I was able to detect existing file and display duplicate message but I was not able to create functionality to suppress overwriting by Yes/No buttons choice with a code below

```
//check for duplicates
if (!is_file($targetFile)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    $html_content="";

}
//if so rename as .datestamp.bak
else {
    $old = $targetFile;
    $new = $targetFile.".".date('YmdHis').'.bak';
    rename($old,$new);

    $html_content="Duplicate document detected.";

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);  
}

    $json_array=array('html_content'=>$html_content);

    header('Content-type: text/json');
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json_array)
```

My question is can `dropzone.js` has ability to provide that kind of functionality (to need to notify user that file already exists and is going to be overwritten with new one by executing choice) or I need to look at something else like extending that library by jQuery AJAX calls?

Comment: Unclear question. How do you classify `duplicate` document? Same name? If right, you can prevent to continue uploading instead of overriding.

Comment: Same way as any system do - by the same filename. I need to notify user that file already exists and is going to be overwritten with new one and old one is going to be backed up (as is there already in the code) and user will interact with Yes/No functionality if he wants to upload and overwrite or do not continue.

Comment: Try to open `dropzone.js`, press Ctrl + F and type: `addedfile: function (file)` or `thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl)`. Edit it

Comment: You can start with: `console.log(file['name'])`